# AC Bonus Class Feature

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, armor-class

Other than Monk, Swashbuckler, and Brawler, what are some classes that give you an AC bonus from having the class?

Answer (score 2):

### Base Classes

You have a few base classes, some of them have similar conditions for their AC bonus, such as being unarmored and not wearing a shield:

- [Monk](http://archivesofnethys.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monk) (and [Unchained Monk](http://archivesofnethys.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monk%20(Unchained)));
- [Gunslinger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger/#TOC-Nimble-Ex-);
- [Brawler](http://archivesofnethys.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Brawler);
- [Swashbuckler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/#TOC-Nimble-Ex-);
- [Shifter](http://archivesofnethys.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Shifter);
- [Self Perfection Psychic](http://archivesofnethys.com/PsychicDisciplinesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Self-Perfection);
- [Medium](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/medium/#Spirits) with a Guardian spirit;

These classes grant *passive* AC bonuses, that will increase your AC for no other reason than simply having the class and meeting the requirement (such as being unarmored). The Medium requires you to activate, at the start of a day, a specific spirit that lasts 24 hours, so I'm also counting that as a possible source of AC bonus.

### Archetypes

You have many archetypes that grant certain AC bonuses, but considering the archetypes from a base class that does not already grant a bonus to AC, we got a shorter list:

- [Sacred Attendant Cleric](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo-cleric-archetypes/sacred-attendant/);
- [Elemental Ascetic Kineticist](http://archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Kineticist%20Elemental%20Ascetic);
- [Esoteric Magus](http://archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Magus%20Esoteric);
- [Stonelord Paladin](http://archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Paladin%20Stonelord);
- [Sacred Fist Warpriest](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/archetypes/paizo-warpriest-archetypes/sacred-fist/);

But this is no exhaustive list, many of the archetypes from the base classes keep their AC bonus from the non-archetyped version of the class, so you can assume that a good amount of archetypes from those classes also have a bonus to AC.

Comment: I dont think the purpose was to find out all possible ways to increase your AC (which is too broad and changes nearly monthly), so I only listed the bonuses that come straight from being a member of the class. Since the question was closed, I will wait for further clarification before editing the answer. But you are correct about the Kensai/Duelist. As for the mysteries, they don't add, they replace, so that seemed offtopic, and we might soon need an updated and easily accessible [guide to x to y](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o91Z-s0R7Vf2Ujj1lFqGC5W--9JOyU0I6uC9XRIR5to/edit).